# Bootstrap Carousel Plugin image alignment

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[reduce bottom image height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACLCG.jpg)I am student , am trying to use **Bootstrap Carousel Plugin**, And am using  w3school carousel example [https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel&stacked=h] so I need to increase the bottom height Carousel Image buttons it's too low, can any one help me. i have attached a photo below

here is my tried code

```
  <section id="intro" class="clearfix" style="
      padding: 80px 0 60px 0;
      padding-top: 80px;
      padding-right: 0px;
      padding-bottom: 60px;
      padding-left: 0px;
  ">
          <div class="container d-flex h-100">

        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>


          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
              <img src="img/dog2.jpg" alt="Los Angeles"  class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
              <img src="img/duffy-brook-350228-2000x1333.jpg" alt="Chicago"  class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
              <img src="img/dog2.jpg" alt="New york"  class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
            </div>
          </div>


          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please post the code which you have tried. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `top:50%` to `carousel-indicators`

```css
.carousel-indicators {
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Carousel Example</h2>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

If you want to reduce the height of your `carousel`, you can specify the `height` as per your requirement

```css
.carousel-inner {
  height: 50vh!important
}

 .carousel-inner .item.active,
.carousel-inner .item {
  height: 50vh!important;
}

.item img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%!important;
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Carousel Example</h2>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: They've said the buttons are too high no?

Comment: As per his image he needs the `carousel-indicators` in center as per my assumption. Tho i'm not clear with his question

Comment: thanks, i need to reduce the bottom height also, can you please help me [https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACLCG.jpg]

Comment: @shivmysuru please check my second snippet. Have done the same

Comment: @SaiManoj thanks, it is worked for me. but in **mobile view** buttons are moved away from the image(Responsive View)

Comment: @shivmysuru please accept my answer if it helped you. Happy coding :)

Comment: @SaiManoj I accepted  your answer :) but in mobile view bootstrap buttons are moved away from the image(Responsive View)

Comment: @shivmysuru updated the second snippet. Please check it now

Answer (score 0):

Your `ol` has `bottom: 10px;`

Change the value of the `bottom` attribute to change the vertical position

Add the following CSS

**CSS**

```
ol.carousel-indicators {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ol style="bottom: 0;" class="carousel-indicators">
```

See example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3qympu54/1/)

Comment: ,only buttons moving to the top, i need to adjust image height also. There is a height (huge space) between them. plese see this image link [https://i.stack.imgur.com/afUsd.png]. image needs be reduced

Comment: @shivmysuru You can use `top` instead of `bottom` in my answer to achieve this, please consider reviewing your question, the question doesn't seem to match the image

Comment: thanks, i need to reduce the bottom height also, can you please help me [https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACLCG.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Carousel Example</h2>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
     

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```